# I keep getting an error running my java program?

Tags: java

i am following along a tutorial and keep getting this Error: Could not find or load main class myfirstprogram.Variables

[image]

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot of your code, post the code instead as a text.

Comment: In your screenshot the class is named `Varibles` not `Variables`... looks like a simple typo.

Comment: post the code in a form that I can copy and test it here....

Comment: You're either compiling it or running it wrong. You don't state how you do either, so... It's a class path issue. (Or a typo as pointed out ;)

Comment: The code in the screenshot is correct, if eccentrically indented and capitalized (and misspelled). If you compile and run it correctly, it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Should be `public static void main(String[] args)`, note the `String` type on the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Right click to the class in the side file explorer and click to **run**.